# One Broadcast receiver for multiple notifications Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am working on an app that reminds the user of an event at a particular date and time. I am having problem using the broadcast receiver. Suppose the user clicks on item 0, then position of the item is 0. I check if the position does equal to 0, then set the specific date and time for the notification. Then receiver class will call the message class to show the message. Based on my code, the receiver method should show three different notification because each has a different id but this is not happening. Only the first notification is shown.

In  MyReceiver I want to have the position variable from arrayadapter that keeps tracks of what item was clicked. But I am not able to do that (at `onItemClick`)

I have more than 94 events, and I don't want to have 94 Broadcast receiver classes to show me the notification for each event. Is THERE ANY WAY I CAN USE ONE RECEIVER CLASS TO SHOW ALL THE NOTIFICATIONS.

I tested it out by having separate Broadcast receiver class for each event and it worked fine. 
This is what I did:

1.I created three different receiver classes
2.In the message class, I have methods for each notification
3. and in each receiver class I called the specific method like this

```
Message nm = new Message();
nm.generateNotification(context);
```

and the main class I did this:

```
Intent myInten2t = new Intent(BuddhaEvent.this, MyReceiver.class);
```

MyReceiver in this case is one of the three receiver classes I implemented.

Could someone please tell me how I can say that `if(position ==0)` show this notification and so on.

This is my Main class.

```
public class BuddhaEvent extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public List<list> myList = new ArrayList<list>();
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notification;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_buddhism_event);


        fill_eventsList();
        fill_ListView();
        clickResponse();

        Button buddah_button_event = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_event_back_buddhism);
        buddah_button_event.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    // public list(String date, int iconId, String details, String name) {

    private void fill_eventsList() {
        myList.add(new list("Jan-24", R.drawable.chris, "Mahayana countries the new year starts on the first full moon day in January.", "Mahayana New Year"));
        myList.add(new list("Feb-2", R.drawable.chris, "Chinese festival celebrated at the turn of the traditional lunisolar Chinese calendar.", "Chinese New Year"));
        myList.add(new list("Feb-15", R.drawable.chris, "Celebrates the day when the Buddha is said to have achieved Parinirvana, or complete Nirvana", "Nirvana Day"));
        myList.add(new list("Mar-23", R.drawable.chris, "Celebration in honour of the Sangha, or the Buddhist community", "Magha Puja Day"));
        myList.add(new list("Apr-22", R.drawable.chris, "Buddhist New Year", "Theravada New Year"));
        myList.add(new list("May-15", R.drawable.chris, "Celebrates the Buddha's birthday", "Wesak - Buddha Day"));
        myList.add(new list("Jul-11", R.drawable.chris, "Honor the spirits of one's ancestors.", "Obon"));
        myList.add(new list("Jul-19", R.drawable.chris, "Celebrates Buddha's teachings of peace and enlightenment", "Asala - Dharma Day"));
        myList.add(new list("Dec-8", R.drawable.chris, "The day that the historical Buddha, Siddhartha Gautama (Shakyamuni), experienced enlightenment", "Bodhi Day"));

    }

    private void fill_ListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<list> listArrayAdapter = new myListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_eventsView);
        list.setAdapter(listArrayAdapter);

    }

    public void clickResponse() {
        ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_eventsView);
        if (l != null) {
            l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View viewClicked,
                                        final int position, long id) {


                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            BuddhaEvent.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Reminder!!");
                    alert.setMessage("Do you want to be reminded of this event in future?");
                    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            if (position == 0) {


                                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                                MyReceiver mr= new MyReceiver();

                                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
                                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
                                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 18);

                                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
                                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
                                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                                calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(BuddhaEvent.this, MyReceiver.class);

                                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(BuddhaEvent.this, 45454, myIntent, 0);

                                AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                            }

                            if (position == 1) {
                                Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                MyReceiver mr= new MyReceiver();

                                calendar2.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
                                calendar2.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
                                calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 18);

                                calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
                                calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 51);
                                calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                                calendar2.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);


                                Intent myInten2t = new Intent(BuddhaEvent.this, MyReceiver.class);
                                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(BuddhaEvent.this, 12322, myInten2t, 0);

                                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                            }

                            if (position == 2) {
                                counter++;

                                Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                MyReceiver mr= new MyReceiver();

                                calendar2.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
                                calendar2.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
                                calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 18);

                                calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
                                calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 52);
                                calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                                calendar2.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);


                                Intent myInten2t = new Intent(BuddhaEvent.this, MyReceiver.class);
                                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(BuddhaEvent.this, 12322, myInten2t, 0);

                                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alert.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }


    private class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<list> {
        public myListAdapter() {
            // what objects are going in there and how are they going to look
            super(BuddhaEvent.this, R.layout.custom_events_layout, myList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_events_layout, parent, false);
            }
            list current_list = myList.get(position);


            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_image);
            imageView.setImageResource(current_list.getIconId());


            TextView titleTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_event);
            titleTxt.setText(current_list.getName());

            EditText text = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_desp);
            text.setText(current_list.getDetails());


            TextView date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_date);
            date.setText(current_list.getDate());

            return itemView;
        }


    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(BuddhaEvent.this, BuddhaScreen.class));
    }
}

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /*Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1);*/
        BuddhaEvent check = new BuddhaEvent();


        Log.i("App", "called receiver method");
        try {
            Message nm = new Message();


            nm.generateNotification(context);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is my message class

```
public class Message {

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void generateNotification(Context context) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, BuddhaNow.class);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notification;

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            notification.setAutoCancel(true);


            notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            notification.setTicker("This is the ticker");
            notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.setContentTitle("Title");
            notification.setContentText("Hello this is the description");

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,1, intent, 0);

            notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager nm1 = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            nm1.notify(1, notification.build());
    }

    public void generateNotification2(Context context) {

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, BuddhaNow.class);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notification2;

            notification2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            notification2.setAutoCancel(true);


            notification2.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            notification2.setTicker("This is the ticker2");
            notification2.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification2.setContentTitle("second title");
            notification2.setContentText("I am the body");

            PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,2, intent2, 0);

            notification2.setContentIntent(pendingIntent2);

            NotificationManager nm2 = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            nm2.notify(2, notification2.build());
        }


    public void generateNotification3(Context context) {

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, BuddhaNow.class);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification2;

        notification2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        notification2.setAutoCancel(true);


        notification2.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        notification2.setTicker("This is the ticker3");
        notification2.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification2.setContentTitle("third title");
        notification2.setContentText("I am the body");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,3, intent2, 0);

        notification2.setContentIntent(pendingIntent2);

        NotificationManager nm2 = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        nm2.notify(3, notification2.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for one you aren't passing in any Extras in your intent.

Comment: @CodeCody what Extras?

Comment: Data that gets passed into an intent. I suggest you read up more on intents https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: More specifically, Intent.putExtra();

Comment: @CodeCody so this is what I did and still can't find any success
'     Intent myIntent = new Intent(BuddhaEvent.this, MyReceiver.class);
      myIntent.putExtra("position", position);'

In Receiver class:
' Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if(extras!=null){
                data = extras.getInt("position");'

Then I did this:
if(data ==1){
                Message nm = new Message();


                nm.generateNotification(context);